# Is any float number | 0 = a fixed number？

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitwise-operators, arithmetic-expressions

Suppose I wrote the codes like this following:

```
console.log((5/3)|0)
```

The result is 1.

However why? In my mind, `|0` means `+0`. But why can it cancel off the fractional part？

Can anyone give me a full understanding of that by showing its inner binary digits and how can I get that result step by step?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do bitwise operations on a floating point value? That usually doesn't work very well.

Comment: I just wanna know why? It's NOT fair to give negative scores if you don't know or wouldn't like to answer my question……:(
If you have free time, you can have a play with that……Have you noticed that?

Comment: [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) `[...]The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.[...]`

Comment: There could be many reasons someone down-voted your question (it wasn't me), http://idownvotedbecau.se/ lists some of the more prominent reasons. I also suggest you [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and read [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), to make sure you have a good question.

Comment: Your question looks OK to me, but complaining about downvotes is going to make people think twice about upvoting.

Comment: The inner binary digits are now given to you. Here a different test case is given, namely 100/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the operator `|` is bitwise OR, and involves analyzing the bits of that float the computer internally stores. This is because all floats are really expressed as 32 bits.

The value `0` has all 32 bits equal to `0`. A `1` or `0` bit OR `0` will still be `1`, `0` respectively, so all 32 bits remain the same.

Normally, all JS numbers are doubles (64-bit floating point numbers). Beware that before the bitwise OR is completed, the JS compiler will *convert* the floating-point operands into its *signed int* form temporarily, meaning that it could result in a different value, notably the truncating of the decimal part. After the bitwise operation is done, JS will convert it back to floating-point numbers.

Here is an example of how a float value is truncated to a signed int after bitwise OR:

```
var x = 100/3.0;
console.log(x);   // outputs 33.333333333333336
console.log(x|0); // outputs 33 (no decimal)
```

## How your bitwise operators work step-by-step

[There is a Mozilla documentation about the Javascript bitwise operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> "The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format."

Step by step, the bits are (let them be single-precision floats for brevity, JS decimals are doubles):

- `100 / 3: 0  10000100  0000101 01010101 01010101`

  - Exponent bit is 132, which is 5 unbiased, the mantissa bit is slightly greater than 1
- `100 / 3` is casted to 32-bit int form before bitwise OR, yielding integer 33
- `33     : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0001`
- `0      : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`
- `33 | 0 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0001` yielding integer 33 again.
- After bitwise operation is completed, 33 is converted back to floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 5/3
> ```

is

```
1.6666666666666667
```

But, as noted in a comment to the question, bitwise operators (like `|`) convert their arguments to signed 32 bit integers. This *truncates* to zero decimal places.

Hence

> ```
> (5/3)|0
> ```

becomes `1|0` which is `1`.

(The intermediate operator of "truncate floating point to integer" cannot be shown in JS, to see that in action you would need something like C where you can perform such operations explicitly.)

Comment: It seems to work like that (the truncation), but is it specified somewhere or is it just an internal mechanism of js engine? I couldn't find any formal statement about this.

Comment: You haven't provided the asker about how the bits are doing step-by-step.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous without getting into the details of IEEE floating point format (which would add no value) that can't be done. (I see you've done that... but avoided the details of the bit exaction needed by the integer cast.)

Comment: @MatusDubrava It will be in the EcmaScript specification.